# how to delete __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my anchor tags:

```
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Daniel Ouro</h3>
      <p>For more information, contact me.</p>
      <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://github.com/DanielOuro15" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dan.ouro22" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-ouro-15176a1b8" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a href="https://discordapp.com/users/SkelletonWhiter#5138" class="discord"><i class="bx bxl-discord"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
        &copy; Copyright <strong><span>Daniel Ouro</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Google Devtools:

```
<footer id="footer"><a>
    </a><div class="container"><a>
      <h3>Daniel Ouro</h3>
      <p>For more information, contact me.</p>
      </a><div class="social-links">
<a class="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
        </a><a href="https://github.com/DanielOuro15" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dan.ouro22" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-ouro-15176a1b8" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a href="https://discordapp.com/users/SkelletonWhiter#5138" class="discord"><i class="bx bxl-discord"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">
    © Copyright <strong><span>Daniel Ouro</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Image showing my code and the hide item on google devtools]

Comment: What code is above the footer? Might be coming from there.

Comment: its my </main> i revirsed all these parts, but the poin is, this bug comes after of <div class="social-links">

Comment: This is very strange, what results do you get in FireFox devtools?

Comment: The same thing happn on the firefox and on operaGX devtools.